# multi-touch support for Android emulator, programmatically

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-touch

From latest SDK, multi-touch is supported via tethered phone. I'm wondering whether it is supported programmatically. In other words, can we test multi-touch triggered functionalities using automated test suites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not. but from sdk-r20 you can use multitouch in emulator with a real phone connected to computer. check [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation) out.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned already. I want to know if there's a way to support multi-touch without tethering.

Comment: no, sdk does not have this feature yet. i heard of it in google io 2012 a few days ago.

Comment: if we know what functions are called to handle multi-touch events, can we hack the system to add this feature? i'm just thinking out loud... thanks for the answer!

Comment: @dacongy It seems so, but one issue is that a lot of the Android code that supports multitouch checks the running system to see if multitouch is available and deactivates the multitouch functionality if it receives a negative repsonse even though you can programmatically generate multitouch events without needing an input device that supports them. I'm having that issue right now as I'm trying to test an application that supports Gingerbread devices but I have no access to devices running Gingerbread so I have to use the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this same problem. First I'm tested to make sure all tethered signals are going through (I had to modify the SDkController app to even get the connection). Now I'm trying to figure out why, when I click the side of the screen or anywhere, it only shows up on the top right (while the debugger from the emulator is giving the correct thing). The  error is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209092/input-multi-touch-not-correct-coordinate-for-android-google-emulator).

I did however figure out how to do it wirelessly and through the terminal. If that is what you're asking the procedure is pretty much the same. You need to root your device or do the adb port command (with USB connected) before un-connecting your device, and it'll work wirelessly.